# Hiding Media Source Links

Tags: images, links, security

I inserted an image onto my page from my WordPress media (Add Media -> Media Library -> Link To = None). However, when I right click on the page to view the source, I noticed the address to my media. How do I hide this address? I think its a security risk that the folder in which my WordPress site lives in (my_renamed_wordpress_directory) is so easily visible. How do I hide this? When I added the image, I selected `Link To: None`. Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://mysite.com/my_renamed_wordpress_directory/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/screenshot1.gif" alt="screenshot1" width="320" height="197" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-53" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Link to none would only remove the hyperlink from the media. If the user clicks on the media, the media will not open separately in a window / tab.

There is no way to hide the link to the resources. There is no security threat of accessing other files from external user.